# How to choose one and only one element in an XML Schema definition

Tags: xml, xsd

apologies if this has been asked before but I have searched the site...

Anyway, I have been trying to work out how to enforce the choice of one and only one element in an XML Schema.

For instance, say you need to choose between only one apple, orange or banana element, but you cannot have NO apples, oranges or banana elements.

Now I've tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Fruit"
            xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Fruit"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

      <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
              <xsd:element name="banana" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="apple" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="orange" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType mixed="true">

</xsd:schema>
```

Now this is great, however `<choice>` is not *one and only one* but is actually *zero or only one*. How would I enforce the cardinality to be one and only one in an XML Schema Definition file?

Comment: Uh, somehow manager to get `mixed="true"` in there... that's obvoisly not meant to be there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this way:

```
<xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
```

Modified schema: I added Fruit - root and changed xsd to xs

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="Fruit">
      <xs:complexType  mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
              <xs:element name="banana" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="apple" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="orange" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: yeah, I've just tested it and works, but I must modify your schema, attached final version - you can check it

Comment: Thanks smas - I really appreciate it!

Comment: Incidentally, it's the MS intellisense that caused me the confusion... when you initially add `<xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">` it adds in the end tag and says that no elements in the invalidates the `minOccurs="1"`... then you add in an element and the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

@smas' response is correct. However, both minOccurs and maxOccurs attributes default to 1 when not explicitly declared in xs:choice ([source](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_choice.asp)). So you could just get rid of the attributes on xs:choice and get the behavior you want.